# Tracing i2c messages from i2c controller driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c, arm64

I would like to trace all the message going through i2c bus for slave with particular address.

For instance messages are sent from:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-exynos5.c#L681
Can content of theses messages be traced out?

On my platform i2c-tools can't be installed.

Comment: Are you asking about physical bus, or about tracing in the driver?

Comment: @0andriy, Through driver using dmesg not from physical bus.

Comment: Configuration option `I2C_DEBUG_BUS` is yours friend: "I2C Bus debugging messages".

Comment: Thanks @0andriy, it helped me and I can see various transaction messages to slave devices. But I can't see what is the content of those messages( what data is sent to slave device). For instance "i2c_adapter i2c-0: master_xfer[0] W, addr=0x58, len=2" , it only tells me that one write is done to slave device at addr 0x58 but what is being written over there ?

Comment: It looks like the kernel's Event Tracing framework has support for dumping I2C message buffer contents (but only the first 64 bytes of the buffer can be dumped this way). For example `echo 'i2c:*' > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/set_event` should turn on all I2C event tracing.

Comment: @IanAbbott, Yeah Thanks for pointing out, meanwhile I just did to read buffer, https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8q2S7ZtB4k/ .Does it looks ok ?

Comment: @Milan As long as you don't need to print out more than 64 bytes, you could use `dev_dbg(&adap->dev, "buffer reads %*phD\n", msgs[ret].len, msgs[ret].buf);` to output them all at once.

Comment: Sorry @IanAbbott but could you please explain how this format specifier works?

Comment: It's one of the extended specifiers for pointer types supported by the kernel's `printk()` and friends. See [printk-formats pointer-types](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-formats.html#pointer-types) or the big comment before the `pointer()` function in the kernel's [lib/vsprintf.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/lib/vsprintf.c).

Comment: @IanAbbott, It helped. Also, I'm wondering if it is possible to get offset addressed within the slave device using the buffer ?

Comment: Yes, if you log both transmit and receive transfers, since the master has to send the offset to the slave.